# I was solving a capacitor problem the other day and encountered a question on redistribution of charges

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, potential, capacitance

When two charged capacitors are connected(**one positive plate with the other ones negative**). I wondered *since there is no electric field outside the capacitors*, then why do the charges flow to balance out the potential of the two connected plates? Also **if only one plate of a capacitor is connected with only one plate of the other** then I guess charges could not flow **even if there's a potential difference between them** as the opposite plate has a constant charge and would want an **equal opposite charge** on it's opposite plate following *gauss's law*.